# Problem in understanding some basic linked list function

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

```
void
LInsert (LIST * l, int x, int pos)
{  
    struct Node *new, *p;   // p: previous node
    // create a new node
    new = (struct Node *) malloc (sizeof (struct Node));
    new->val = x;
    if (pos == 0)
    {               // insert to start
        new->next = l->head;
        l->head = new;
    }
    else
    {               
        // insert after p
        p = l->head;

        while (p != NULL && pos > 1)
        {
            p = p->next;
            --pos;
        }

        if (p == NULL)
        {
            printf ("LInsert: Position not possible\n");
            return;
        }
        new->next = p->next;
        p->next = new;
    }
    l->size++;
}
```

This is a function of inserting  a node to a linked list.  I don't understand a few lines in this program.
In the first if condition there is a line `new->next=l->head;` From my thinking it means that in the "next" part of the new node it will store the what's in the head node(an address probably), but why?. It makes the linked list  a circular linked list but this is just a simple linked list.
Also near the end `new->next=p->next` what does this mean.It makes the linked list circular again.
Hope the indentation is correct I always get people yelling at me for wrong indentation
Here is the complete code which includes struc declaration and stuff

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int  val;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct List {
    struct Node *head;
    int size;
};

// LIST is new name for "struct List"
typedef struct List LIST;

void LInit(LIST *l){ // Initialize list to empty
    l->head = NULL;  // pointer to first node
    l->size = 0;     // number of nodes
}

int LGetPos(LIST *l, int x) {
    struct Node *p;
    int i=0;
    // go through all nodes
    for (p=l->head; p!=NULL; p=p->next)
        if (p->val == x) return i;   // found
        else i++;                    // next
    return -1;   // not found in the list
}

int LGetAt(LIST *l, int pos) {
    struct Node *p=l->head;
    int i;
    // go to position
    for(i=0; p!=NULL && i<pos; i++) p = p->next;
    if(p) return p->val;  // if exists, return it
    else { printf("LDelete: Position not exist\n"); return -99; }
}

void LInsert(LIST *l, int x, int pos) {
    struct Node *new, *p;  // p: previous node
    // create a new node
    new = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new->val = x;
    if(pos==0) {  // insert to start
        new->next = l->head;
        l->head = new;
    }
    else {  // insert after p
        p = l->head;
        while(p!=NULL && pos>1) { p = p->next; --pos; }
        if(p==NULL) { printf("LInsert: Position not possible\n"); return; }
        new->next = p->next;
        p->next = new;
    }
    l->size++;
}

void LDelete(LIST *l, int pos) {
    struct Node *p, *d;  // p: previous
    if(l->head == NULL) return;
    if(pos==0) {  // delete first node
        d = l->head;
        l->head = d->next;
    }
    else {  // delete after p
        p = l->head;
        while(pos>1 && p) { p = p->next; --pos; }
        if(p==NULL) { printf("LDelete: Position not exist\n"); return; }
        d = p->next;
        p->next = p->next->next;
    }
    l->size--;
    free(d);
}

int LIsEmpty(LIST * l){
    return (l->size == 0);
}

int LSize(LIST * l){
     return (l->size);
}

void LDisplay(LIST *l) {
    struct Node *p;
    printf("List: ");
    for(p=l->head; p!=NULL; p=p->next)
        printf("--> %d ", p->val);
    printf("\n");
}

int LHeadOf(LIST *l) {
    if (!LIsEmpty(l)) return l->head->val;
    else {
        printf("LHeadOf: Linked list empty\n");
        return -99;
    }
}


int main() {
    LIST list;

    LInit(&list);
    LDisplay(&list);

    LInsert(&list, 3, 0);
    LInsert(&list, 4, 0);
    LInsert(&list, 5, 2);
    LDisplay(&list);

    printf("Value at 1: %d\n", LGetAt(&list, 1));

    printf("Location of 4: %d\n", LGetPos(&list, 4));

    LDelete(&list, 1);
    LDisplay(&list);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Re "*From my thinking*", Backwards. The right-hand side is assigned to the left-hand side. A pointer to the head node (`l->head`) is assigned to the the new node's `next` field (`new->next`).

Comment: new->next=l->head does not store "what's in the head node", it stores the address as you observe. You need to get a clear picture of pointers. I suggest drawing pictures. val stores a number, clearly, and next is an address of another node. You haven't shown what the struct has, but if head points to the first item, it does make 'circular' links. no problem with that.

Comment: @john Would it be the same if i remove. I kinda getting it but I'm not sure. Is it for the while loop. because there is a condition p!=NULL

Comment: I will update my question with the whole program as it is just a part of it

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand a few lines in this program

Okay - let's take a look of those lines...

> here is a line `new->next=l->head;` From my thinking it means that in the "next" part of the new node it will store the what's in the head node(an address probably), but why?

That line is used to insert the new element **in front** of the current head element. So

```
new->next=l->head;  // Make the new element point to current head
l->head = new;      // Change head to point to the new element as it is now the front element
```

> Also near the end `new->next=p->next` what does this mean.It makes the linked list circular again.

Well, it doesn't make the list circular. It simply insert the new element somewhere in the middle of the list.

```
    new->next = p->next;  // Make new point to the element after p
    p->next = new;        // Make p point to new
                          // In this way new has between inserted after p and
                          // before the element that folloed p
```